# Django "no such table found" error even after makemigrations

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

To save time, I delete db.sqlite3 file and every 000x.py related to database change. I re-run makemigrations and migrate, rebuild database and everything comes back to normal at last. I didn't understand the issue yet but it's resolved to me.

I recently add a new table RunningTable in my models file and I do execute both:
`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Both commands returned success. And I checked files in APPName/migrations/000x.py and the RunningTable lies really there. But my code runs with this table not found error.

I tried check by Django shell with below picture shows. As you can see, I can import it from the correct path. But failed when I call RunningTable.objects.all(). Is there anyone can tell me why this error happens?
Add more: This table have no data yet. Does that matter?

models.py code(partly):

```
class RunningTable(models.Model):
    instance_id = models.IntegerField()
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = PROJNAME_CHOICES, default = "ROMA")
    is_running = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_true_run = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    fake_run_result = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default = "")
    create_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

[image]

Add another screen(I deleted files under migrations folder and regenerate the 0001_initial.py again, as you can see below. The table
is created although with no data at the begining):
[image]

Maybe my last try is to delete the db.sqlite3 file but I'd like to find out my exact fault/miss or have a better way to debug this issue.

I can see the auto-generated snippet in the 0001_init.py, It seems quite correct:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='RunningTable',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('instance_id', models.IntegerField()),
                ('project_name', models.CharField(choices=[('ROMA', 'ROMA'), ('PDK', 'PDK'), ('PMIC', 'PMIC'), ('OTHER', 'OTHER')], default='ROMA', max_length=100)),
                ('is_running', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_true_run', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('start_datetime', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('complete_datetime', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('fake_run_result', models.CharField(default='', max_length=1024)),
                ('create_datetime', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: Can you please share the model code? Also , please cross verify if the table is created in the database or not after successfull migration. In addition, Have you tried to debug ?

Comment: I think I did. New screen updated.

Comment: make sure you register the table in admin.py file

Comment: @Ivan Thank you. I have deleted/reset everything and resolved the issue. I can't answer your question since the environment is ruined. Your link seems resolved a issue of very alike. If I met the same issue later I'll try this and reply again. I think your link will help others needed.

Comment: @Ivan I think I had read this post in your link before I create this post. I just didn't like the idea of deleting the db.sqlite3 in his answer so I create a new one. I didn't remember if I had tried migrate --fake appname zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting Your Current DataBase file and all Migrations files.. with looks like in migration folder of your current app

```
001_something.py
```

And Run Makemigrations and Migrate

Comment: I had done that repeatedly. Only I'm reluctant to delete the db.sqlite3 file. I expect a better way.

Comment: I add more information and screen shot.

Comment: Yes, deleting db.sqlite3 file do resolve my problem. To saving time, I did that at last. I didn't do that at first time for I don't want to re-build the database. I hope I won't meet the issue in future, since it seems I didn't understand the real reason yet. I'll put the question to a close.